# How to limit multiple numbers by filtering multiple columns on MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to get 50 questions from 4 different categories from the database. I want a different number of questions from each of the 4 different categories; my result set must contain first category 12 questions, second category 20 questions, third 10, and fourth category 8 questions. In total 50 question from my question table.
I used the ***LIMIT*** function for this. But when I have more than one column, I'm confused.

**This is my table:**

```
 | category_id| question-text| Col3 |
 |------------|--------------|------|
 |    1       |  sample      |  ieb |
 |    2       |  sample      |  aem |
 |    3       |  sample      |  atd |
 |    4       |  sample      |  oui |
 |    1       |  sample      |  ieb |
 |    2       |  sample      |  aem |
 |    3       |  sample      |  atd |
 |    4       |  sample      |  oui |
 |    1       |  sample      |  ieb |
 |    2       |  sample      |  aem |
 |    3       |  sample      |  atd |
 |    4       |  sample      |  oui |
 |    1       |  sample      |  ieb |
 |    2       |  sample      |  aem |
 |    3       |  sample      |  atd |
 |    4       |  sample      |  oui |
```

And I need this result:
 5 questions from category # 1.
 3 questions from category # 2.
 2 questions from category # 3.
 7 questions from category # 4.

Comment: How do 5, 3, 2, & 7 relate to 12, 20, 10, & 8?

Comment: Forget the numbers. they were just an example. What's important is to use more than one limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) query to get all your questions at once:

```
(SELECT * FROM question WHERE categori_id=1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 12)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM question WHERE categori_id=2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM question WHERE categori_id=3 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM question WHERE categori_id=4 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 8)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Nick. Good night <3